# Incorrect hierarchy in testng.xml file created programmatically and failed to run

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

I have a requirement to create custom testng.xml file based on the inputs. I was able to create one successfully but the groups in the suite level are misplaced i.e below the parameters and the listeners instead of the top of the parameters i.e groups should be placed first and then the others as specified in the below error.

> The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors|
>    suite-files)*)".

Below is piece of code to create the xml file.

```
        XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();
        xmlSuite.setName("CustomSuiteFile");
        xmlSuite.setParallel(ParallelMode.TESTS);
        xmlSuite.setThreadCount(1);
        List<String> group = new ArrayList<String>();
        group.add("Regression");
        group.add("Smoke");
        xmlSuite.setIncludedGroups(group);
        xmlSuite.setListeners(Arrays.asList("Utils.TestListener"));
        parameters.put("reportPath", "C://ExtentReports//ExtentReportResult");
        xmlSuite.setParameters(parameters);
```

xml file created for the above code but this throws the above specified error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" name="CustomSuiteFile" parallel="tests">
  <parameter name="reportPath" value="C://ExtentReports//ExtentReportResult"/>
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="Utils.TestListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="Regression"/>
      <include name="Smoke"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
  <test thread-count="1" name="Chrome" parallel="tests">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
  </test> <!-- Chrome -->
</suite> <!-- CustomSuiteFile -->
```

But below is the expected (**the group is placed first and then the others in the suite level**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" name="CustomSuiteFile" parallel="tests">
<groups>
    <run>
      <include name="Regression"/>
      <include name="Smoke"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
  <parameter name="reportPath" value="C://ExtentReports//ExtentReportResult"/>
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="Utils.TestListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <test thread-count="1" name="Chrome" parallel="tests">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
  </test> <!-- Chrome -->
</suite> <!-- CustomSuiteFile -->
```

Please advise if i'm wrong somewhere and how to achieve the expected one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a brief look at the XmlSuite source it is obvious that it does not produce XML that is conformant to the DTD. I suggest poking the author.

Comment: @forty-two Yeah i have created one (https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2231#issue-555736496)